# Datasource best practices question

Tags: asp.net, datasource, sqldatasource

This is probably not a difficult project, but I'm not sure of the best way to handle it.

I have an ASP.Net page that needs to query a db for some info (a list of about 12 email addresses) that are used throughout the single-page application (basically a set of 8 buttons, each of which puts an entry into another DB table which includes a message [different for each button] and the email address [from the first db] the message should be sent to).

The list of addresses rarely changes. At what point should my application query the DB for the addresses? Doing it at the button press seems like a waste, since I'll be making the same query and obtaining the same results over and over. I was thinking of opening my datasource and using a SqlDataReader and storing the list of email addresses into a string array, but where is the best place to do that so the data is persisted, yet not queried repeatedly (as you may be able to tell, I am not great at ASP, and I'm still fuzzy on what the lifetime of variables are - application, session, or just while the page is processing).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx). Look for GetProductData() method implementation in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972379.aspx)

Comment: Thank you (and to others who pointed me in this direction). I'll do some reading up on the cache and go that route.

Answer (score 0):

In your data layer, put the results of the query into the [cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx).

In the method, you first check if the cache entry exists, if not, you call the DB and populate the cache with the results. If it does, you return the cached values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to looking into using the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The Cache is most likely what you need:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx

Short version is that you can stick an object in there and set expiration conditions.  Such as having it expire after a fixed amount of time, after a certain amount of time goes by without it being accessed, when another value in the cache changes, or when the underlying data in the database changes.

I usually wrap my caching in properties/methods that will attempt to get the value from cache if it is present and then go back to the database if it is not (either has never been read before or has expired).